How to prove that the sum of 3 Subspaces are not direct?
We have in $\mathbb{R}^5$ subspaces, $U_{1} = \left \{ (a,a,a+b,b,b):a,b\in \mathbb{R} \right \}, U_{2} = \left \{ (a,2a,a,3b,b):a,b\in \mathbb{R} \right \}, U_{3} = \left \{ (3a,a,8a,-a,3a):a,b\in \mathbb{R} \right \}$
Show that $U_{1}+U_{2}+U_{3}$ is not direct.
I calculate the following,
$ (a,a,a+b,b,b) + (a,2a,a,3b,b) + (3a,a,8a,-a,3a) = (5a,4a,10a+b,4b-a,3a+2b) = 0$
to find out if the null vector has more instances than only one.
$$
 5a=0 \iff a=0, 
 10a+b=0 \iff b=0
$$
but with my try, I can only find that the sum is direct.
Could someone tell me where is my mistake?

Regarding your calculations, you should have changed the symbols to get
$$ (a,a,a+b,b,b) + (c,2c,c,3d,d) + (3e,e,8e,-e,3e) = (a+c+3e,a+2c+e,a+b+c+8e,b+3d-e,b+d+3e) = (0,0,0,0,0).$$
Note that
$$(0,0,0,0,0)=\underbrace{(0,0,0,0,0)}_{\displaystyle\in U_1}+\underbrace{(0,0,0,0,0)}_{\displaystyle\in U_2}+\underbrace{(0,0,0,0,0)}_{\displaystyle\in U_3}$$
and
$$(0,0,0,0,0)=\underbrace{(1,1,2,1,1)}_{\displaystyle\in U_1}+\underbrace{(-\frac{2}{5},-\frac{4}{5},-\frac{2}{5},-\frac{6}{5},-\frac{2}{5})}_{\displaystyle\in U_2}+\underbrace{(-\frac{3}{5},-\frac{1}{5},-\frac{8}{5},\frac{1}{5},-\frac{3}{5})}_{\displaystyle\in U_3}.$$
Since $(0,0,0,0,0)$ can be written in more than one way as a sum $u_1+u_2+u_3$, with $u_1=U_1$, $u_2\in U_2$, and $u_3\in U_3$, we can conclude that $U_1+U_2+U_3$ is not a direct sum.

Thanks, that make sense. I tried with the same variables.
